# Php easy way to read comment data from file

Tags: php, file

Is there any easy way to read comment header from file (css/js/php)

like

```
/*
Script Name : somescript
Author : Me
Version : 1.1
*/
```

As simple key-value array?

Comment: Yeah, but I suggest looking for a tool that is already build.

Comment: I prefer [doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/)

Answer (score 2):

### PHP:

Check out [Tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php).

To get all the comments in a file named file.php you'd do:

```
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents("file.php"));
$comments = array();
foreach($tokens as $token) {
    if($token[0] == T_COMMENT || $token[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT) {
        $comments[] = $token[1];
    }
}
print_r($comments);
```

### CSS:

```
jQuery.get("file.css", null, function(data) {
    var comments = data.match(/\/\*.*\*\//g);
    for each (var c in comments) 
        alert(c);
});
```

Comment: added solution for CSS

Comment: I need php solution. I've made my own solution using line by line file reading.